# How to make an Android Studio connection with mongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, android-studio

I want to create a connection with a local MongoDB using Android Studio, I have searched online, but I only found information about `mlabs`.

What I want to know is, if there's a way to create a connection locally and utilise the db within Android Studio.

Comment: Do you want to do mongodb database operation using android?

Comment: yes. I want to operate the mongoDB with respect to an android app

Comment: Have you looked into firebase?

Comment: I don't want to work with firebase, the reason behind this is that I'm basically working on a project which intakes continuous hardware data for which mongoDB is best as it can also work locally without any use of internet.

Answer (score 1):

You can create REST API to communicate with the MongoDB Database via Spring boot. Also for Calling those APIs you can use Retrofit/Volley to get Response from REST APIs.You can certainly have a look at this Medium post for more information. ->

[MongoDB and REST API](https://medium.com/@gtommee97/rest-api-java-spring-boot-and-mongodb-4dffbcabbaf5)

This Post will teach you how to create API to communicate with the Database via REST API using SPRING Java Framework, using POST Man tool you can verify your API is working or not and once it's verified you can use any networking library RETROFit/ Volley to call get JSONResponse from those APIs and using GSON or any other mapping libraries you can map Json Objects to appropriate Java Objects and for that you have to create Model classes(POJO Classes). This all steps you need to do in order to communicate with MongoDB and Android. Hope this helps.